# while Controller is not working properly in jmeter and beanshell preprocessor not working properly

Tags: jmeter

I am using this script on Jmeter:
[image]

inside beanShellProcessor i got this code:

```
import java.lang.*;

int timestampInt=0;
String timestamp="";

timestamp=vars.get("timestamp_start");
//System.out.println(timestamp);
timestampInt = Integer.parseInt(timestamp);
timestampInt+=1;
timestamp_start=Integer.toString(timestampInt);
System.out.println(timestamp_start);

vars.put(timestamp_start,"timestamp_start");
```

I am getting timestamp_start and timestamp_end from the command line (`${__P(timestamp_start,1451404741)}`).
in order to stop the while loop I am using this condition:

```
${__javaScript("${timestamp_start}" <=  "${timestamp_end}")}
```

however I see that my code does not increment my timestamp variable it remains the same , can you help on that? thanks!

Comment: Check the value of `${timestamp_start}` and  `${timestamp_end}` exactly before the while control, you can do this with insert a Debug sampler before while controler. I think the the condition is not reached and the thread never reaches the BeanShellPreProcessor

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the last line of your script to

```
vars.put("timestamp_start",timestamp_start);
```

According to JavaDoc [JMeterVariables.put(String key, String value))](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#put(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) first argument should be JMeter variable name and the second - variable value.

In order to see additional debugging information you can add `debug();` statement as the first line of your Beanshell script.

See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) for more information on using Beanshell in your JMeter tests.